# In Eclipse, how to change the colour of the selected console text's highlighting colour?

Tags: eclipse

Please see image for high lighted color to change. [Here is the highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Cf5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that appears to be a color setting which cannot be changed within Eclipse.

On Windows 10 it definitely uses the operating system default for **Selected Text** (which for me is blue), but you can change it through the **Personalize** settings for Windows. I verified this, but obviously that will impact all your applications, not just the Eclipse Console, so it's not a very good option.

I don't know things works on Linux or Mac, but I assume there is a similar approach available.

Notes:

1. You can easily change other color settings for the Eclipse Console. Just right click anywhere within the **Console** window and select **Preferences...** from the context menu. Then click on any of the colors shown (e.g. "*Background color*") to change it. Note that there is no option offered for changing the background color of selected text.
2. I also tried changing the Theme for Eclipse but the background color for selected text in the Console always remained the same as the Windows default regardless of the theme chosen. (I don't know of any technical reason why this setting in the Console cannot be customized though - perhaps someone else can explain?)